# Web application Testing

Tags: testing

Hi guys  i have developed a web application that is hosted on client side test server, i have to check the response time of each page (loading) but i cant install any tool on the test server totally confused. guys give some idea.

Answer (score 1):

Use FireFox and the Life-Of-Request info plugin. It will tell you how long until first byte, how long to display entire page. How many requests were made. Other stuff.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/lori-life-of-request-info/

Does this need to be automated or can you do a one off for a few pages and call it a day?

Answer (score 0):

FireBug add-on for Firefox (http://getfirebug.com/). It will help you with quite a few things related to web app development / testing. Specifically page response time can be tested in Net panel of FireBug: http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel.